# Append something to selected text with jquery

Tags: jquery, append, right-click, selectedtext

I'm trying to append an `<a>` tag in to selected text when user right click on it.i searched over the stack , no matches found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dealing with selected text reliably is a bit tricky cross-browser. Tim Down's library [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) can be useful there, he's smoothed over a lot of the browser idiosyncrasies. (Even if you don't want to use the library, you can study it for the techniques.)

One of the [core Rangy demos](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/core.html) is surrounding selected text with an element, using [the `RangyRange#surroundContents` method](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/RangyRange#surroundContents%28Node_node%29). The code for that in the demo looks like this:

```
function getFirstRange() {
    var sel = rangy.getSelection();
    return sel.rangeCount ? sel.getRangeAt(0) : null;
}
function surroundRange() {
    var range = getFirstRange();
    if (range) {
        var el = document.createElement("span");
        el.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
        try {
            range.surroundContents(el);
        } catch(ex) {
            if ((ex instanceof rangy.RangeException || Object.prototype.toString.call(ex) == "[object RangeException]") && ex.code == 1) {
                alert("Unable to surround range because range partially selects a non-text node. See DOM Level 2 Range spec for more information.\n\n" + ex);
            } else {
                alert("Unexpected errror: " + ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'd be doing much the same, but with an `a` rather than a `span`.

Comment: Nice job , but is there any solution to do this without a plugin ?

Comment: @bizzare: As I said above, if you don't want to use Rangy as-is, you can still study how Rangy does it and apply the techniques. Just look at how `getSelection` and `surroundContents` work. This is the joy of Tim having made [Rangy open source](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/source/browse/trunk/src/#src%2Fjs%2Fcore), not obfuscating it.

Answer (score 0):

`EDIT` Noticed you were talking about selected text a little too late.

Maybe you could check [document.elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.elementFromPoint), only supported in FireFox I think.

Are you looking for something like this:

Html:

```
<div id="rightclick">
Right Click me:   
</div>​
```

Javascript:

```
$("#rightclick").mousedown(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 3) {
        $(this).append("<a href='http://www.google.com'>Link</a>");
    }
});
​
```

See the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/BgW7x/2/

Comment: The OP said **selected** text (both in the question and with a tag)

Comment: Oh he means get the selected text on right click, oh boy, I'm so sorry scanned the question too fast.

Comment: Yeah i want the  selected text your code append a link in end of the div

Comment: this is not what he wants.